# A sequence of harmonic functions on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ converging in distribution must necessarily converge locally uniformly to an harmonic function.

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am self studying the Rudin's book of Functional Analysis and I stumbled upon this problem. Given a sequence $\{ f_{j} \}_{j}$ of harmonic functions on an open set $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2},$ if $\{ f_{j} \}_{j}$ converges  to a distribution $\Gamma$ then $\Gamma$ has to be an harmonic function on $\Omega.$
My attempted solution was the following. The main point was to prove that $\{ f_{j}\}_{j}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^{\infty}(K)$ for every compact $K.$
Since the function $f_{i}$ is harmonic for every $i$ given a compact set $K$ we have that
$$ f_{i}(x)-f_{j}(x)=\int_{B(x,r)} \frac{1}{\vert B(x,r) \vert} (f_{i}(y)-f_{j}(y))\, dy, $$ where $B(x,r)$ is a ball of radius $r,$ with $r$ suitably small and $x$ is a point of $K$.
Maybe if I could write this last integral using a test function then I would  have concluded, but since now I did not get any idea. Once this point is done the conclusion follows easily: the pointwise limit of the sequence $\{f_{j}\}_{j}$ fulfills the mean value property.

Comment: The Laplacian is continuous on distributions, so the limit function is a distribution annihilated by the Laplacian...

Comment: @paulgarrett but how do I make sure that the distributional laplacian is the laplacian of an actual function? I mean it is true because of the Weyl's lemma, but I hoped there was another way, because the exercise specifically requires to prove locally uniform convergence.

Comment: Ah, if the exercise constrains you, I guess you'll have to experiment to find something that meets the requirements... :)

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but the integral on a ball can be replaced by an integral against a rotationally invariant test function.

Comment: @justt yes that was exactly what I was searching for, could you please give a reference or at least a hint on how to prove this fact?

Comment: You can start from the fact that you can replace the average on a ball by the average on a circle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_measure 

Then a radial test function is just the integral of infinitely many weighted circle measures.

Comment: @justt thanks for the help!